# output an array using factorial operator

Tags: c++

i am new to operator overloading. 
following is my code i am trying to do operator overloading of ! operator to get an array printed out on my console. I am not getting any error but !data isn't being call when i run the main function. i can't find anything on the internet as there is no operator other then << that is being used for overloading. that too with out<<. but here i can't change my main format so i need to find a way to make it work. can anybody point me in the right direction?
header file

```
class Data
{
private:
    int* integers;
    int size;
public:
    Data(int*  , int );
    Data& operator += (int);
    Data& operator +(int);
    Data& operator =(const Data &c);
    friend void operator!(const Data &c);

};
```

.cpp file

```
Data::Data(int *arrayint, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            arrayint[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayint[i] = 0;
        }
    }

}

Data &Data::operator+=(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        integers[i] = integers[i] + n;
    }
    return *this;
}


Data &Data::operator +(int n) 
{
    return Data(*this) += n;


}

Data &Data::operator=(const Data & c)
{
    integers = c.integers;
    return *this;
}


void operator!(const Data & c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size; i++)
    {
        cout << c.integers[i];
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

main

```
int main() {

    int a[10] = { 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20 };

    Data *data = new Data(a, 10);
    !data;

    data = data + 5;
    !data;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You never set `data.size` to any specific value. Therefore the reference to `self->size` in `operator+` and `operator!` both invoke undefined behavior. Similarly, you never set `data.integers` to any specific value.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You call !  on a pointer.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code that I don't even know where to begin. Your `Data` class doesn't do at all what I think you think it does. Your syntax choices do not make sense. You use pointers and `new` where you don't need to. And `!` doesn't do what you think it does. It feels like you're trying to do something rather advanced (a class with a special interface using overloaded operators) without having the fundamentals of the language down.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor never sets `integer` nor `size`. You can set them using a member initializer list:

```
Data::Data(int *arrayint, int size)
    : integers(arrayint), size(size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            arrayint[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayint[i] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can set the variables in the body of your function. In this instance, I changed the name of the function parameter to be different than the member variable.

```
Data::Data(int *arrayint, int size_)
{
    integers = arrayInt;
    size = size_;
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            arrayint[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayint[i] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, your definition of the `!` operator doesn't match its use. In the definition, you declare the parameter as `const Data&`, but in its use, you pass a `Data*`. Either change the function declaration to `Data*` or change the use to `!*data`.

Comment: still the !data didn't get called(its getting skipped when i try to debug my code)

Comment: can you elaborate on how do i do that. i tried changing but it redlines operator giving error too much operators